# Reading SQL from file and SQLiteOpenHelper

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I need to include an existing `SQLiteDatabase` in my Android app and I also want the ability to download and install a new db. I did some research and my first working solution came [from here](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications). I didn't like that solution, for one thing, it assumes that the database will always be in a fixed path and other oddities.

So, rather than putting the existing database file in the assets, I exported the database to a SQL file, read it in, and then in the `onCreate()` method of my `SQLiteOpenHelper`, I call a new method  `updateDatabase` with an open `DataInputStream` with the file data.
I ran into a few issues, which I think I solved, but I'm sure I didn't think of all the issues, which are:

1. When `SQLiteOpenHelper`'s `onCreate` method is called, the database has been created, it is open, and `inTransaction()` is `true`.  As a result, if the imported sql file includes `BEGIN TRANSACTION`, an exception is thrown and if the sql String contains statements creating `'android_metadata'` yet another exception.  So, I added a simple search using `String.contains()` looking for these keywords, and set a `boolean` `doExecute`  to `false` to avoid executing them.  So a question is, is there a better SQL class or method to filter this, or even a better regexp method?
2. Similar issue with having unexpected line breaks in the SQL file.  I read the file with `readLine()` and to look for line breaks, I simply use `String.trim()` on the line, then check for `endsWith(";")`.  This puts some constraints on my input file, like not having multiple statements on a single line.  So, is there a better way to pre-process SQL from a file?

Here's the code I use to create my db after I've gotten a `DataInputStream` from the `assets` resource or from a download:

```
    public boolean updateDatabase(DataInputStream inStream, SQLiteDatabase db, boolean doClear) throws Error {
    String sqlStatement = null;
    boolean result = true;
    boolean inOnCreate = true;
    boolean wasInTransaction;

    if(doClear) dropDatabase();

    // if called from onCreate() db is open and inTransaction, else getWritableDatabase()
    if(db == null) {
        inOnCreate = false;
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    wasInTransaction = db.inTransaction();  // see NB below

    boolean doExecute;
    try {
        while ((sqlStatement = inStream.readLine()) != null) {
            // trim, so we can look for ';'
            sqlStatement.trim();
            if(!sqlStatement.endsWith(";")) {
                continue;   // line breaks in file, get whole statement
            }

            // NB - my file (exported from SQLite Database Browser starts with "BEGIN TRANSACTION;". 
            // executing this throws SQLiteException: cannot start a transaction within a transaction
            // According to SQLiteDatabase doc for beginTransaction(), "Transactions can be nested"
            // so this is a problem
            // but... possibly it is an "exclusive transaction" ?
            doExecute = true;
            if(wasInTransaction) {
                // don't execute BEGIN TRANSACTION; or COMMIT;
                if((sqlStatement.contains("BEGIN" ) || sqlStatement.contains("begin" )) &&
                        (sqlStatement. contains("TRANSACTION") || sqlStatement.contains("transaction" ))) {
                    doExecute = false;
                }
                if(sqlStatement.contains("COMMIT") || sqlStatement.contains("commit")) {
                    doExecute = false;
                }
            }   // inTransaction
            // this statement could be in older databases, but this scheme doesn't need, can't have it
            if(sqlStatement.contains("android_metadata")) {
                doExecute = false;
            }
            if(doExecute) {
                try {
                    db.execSQL(sqlStatement);
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    throw(new Error("Error executing SQL " + sqlStatement));
                }   // try/catch
            }   // doExecute
        }   // while()
    } catch (IOException e) {
        result = false; // which won't matter if we throw 
        throw(new Error("Error reading  " + DB_SQL));
    } 

    if(!inOnCreate) {
        db.close();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I've edited your question into (I hope) something better. I'm no sqlite master so I'm not commenting on the sqlite stuff but I think you should try to manage the database yourself, outside of a `SQLiteOpenHelper`. That class is probably designed for simpler scenarios with a more static database than what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks, Luksprog, and in retrospect, I guess I should probably have have asked the questions about parsing the sql file content in a separate topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't want to have you cop out early on such ambitious and elegant implementations, but if you have your database already made and checked with a database browser and all, have you considered [SQLite Asset Helper?](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) If your main issue was being forced to use the asset folder, this method `lib` let's you use a file from any specified directory. Moreover, it allows for handling the raw `.db` file. Worth checking out.

Comment: Thanks @mango.  Don't worry about me copping out, I'm always looking for shortcuts, though I do like to understand the underlying code to anything I do use.  That's an excellent link that helps me understand the notion of the SQLiteOpenHelper a lot better.  Not wanting to switch gears again in the project, I will keep it on hand and possibly use some concepts in my own code.  I didn't even realize that get[Readable|Writable]Database were override-able.  And it presents answers to some of my questions about parsing files with sql statements.